# Rendering video sequence editor by scripting

Tags: rendering, scripting, video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to render all individual strips that I have in the video sequence editor in separate files automatically.

I started this script:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
all_strips = list(sorted(scene.sequence_editor.sequences, key = lambda x: x.frame_final_start))

bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = "/Users/***/Blender/mkv/"
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.image_settings.file_format = "FFMPEG"

for strip in all_strips:
    if strip.type == "MOVIE":
        start = strip.frame_final_start
        end = strip.frame_final_end
        bpy.context.scene.frame_start = start
        bpy.context.scene.frame_end = end
        bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True, use_viewport=True)
```

but I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.79/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Could not open file for writing
```

Is there something wrong with `bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True, use_viewport=True)`, with some context maybe?

Comment: Check your permissions to write to that filepath, or if it even exists.  The error is telling you it cannot open the file for writing.

Comment: I feel so stupid. I had checked that the directory indeed existed and that I had the right to write in it, but it seems that by specifying ```bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = "/Users/***/Blender/mkv/"``` Blender tries to create the file with the directory name (I thought Blender added automatically the filename with the start and end frames but whatever...). I changed it to: ```bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = "/Users/***/Blender/mkv/" + str(n_strip) + ".mkv"``` inside the loop and it now works perfectly. Many thanks for the hint!

Comment: Hi. If you have an answer, please post it in the answer box below.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that by specifying:

`bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = "/Users/***/Blender/mkv/"`

Blender tries to create the file with the directory name (I actually thought that Blender added automatically the filename with the start and end frames...). I changed it to:

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.filepath = "/Users/***/Blender/mkv/" + str(n_strip) + ".mkv"
```

inside the loop and it now works perfectly.

Kudos to [batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger) for the hint.