# 2.8 Eevee rendering not working

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have my scene looking really good and its ready to go, but when I hit render animation the warning pops up saying "could not open file for writing". Is there a simple step I'm missing?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39389/deleted-dvd-file-and-could-not-open-file-for-writing and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117346/could-not-open-file-for-writing and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100974/rendering-video-sequence-editor-by-scripting

Comment: Do you set output path?